# Issue Selecting a Sibling With Div Element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below if you click the "button 1" the buttons (2 and 3) get updated. And that works fine.

However, if other buttons are inside a div (example button 4), those buttons don´t get updated. How I can fix it?

```js
function like(button, id) {
  let Button1 = $(button);
  let Button2 = $(button).siblings(".like2");
  let Button3 = $(button).siblings(".like3");
  let Button4 = $(button).siblings(".like4");

  Button1.addClass("pop");
  Button2.addClass("pop");
  Button3.addClass("pop");
  Button4.addClass("pop");
}
```

```css
.pop {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #32322e;
  border-color: #2f2f2c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

  <button class="like" onclick="like(this, 347)">Button 1</button>
  <button class="like2" onclick="like(this, 348)">Button 2</button>
  <button class="like3" onclick="like(this, 349)">Button 3</button>

  <div class="section 2"> <button class="like4" onclick="like(this, 349)">Button 4</button></div>

</div>
```

I tried changing the button4 variable many times like for example

```
let Button4 = $(".section 2").siblings(".like4");
```

But it´s not working so clearly I´m doing it wrong... Please advice.

Comment: What is the `id` parameter for?

Comment: Button 4 isn't a sibling, it's a nephew.

Comment: You can't have spaces in a single class. `.section 2` is selecting a `<2>` element inside a `class="section"` element. You need to use `.section.2` to match an element with `class="section 2"`.

Comment: Each like will have a different id to identify the item liked.

Comment: If I change the name of the class to "section2" how the variable "Button4" should be? i still can not make it work.

Comment: `$(".section2").find(".like4")`. It's not a sibling, it's a child.

Comment: You seem to have a general misunderstanding about all these relationships between elements.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar, the space inside the class and the sibling/child confusion were the problems. It´s working now.

Comment: All these different class names also seem like an antipattern. Usually you give the same class to multiple elements, so you can match them all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Barmar I was able to fix it.

```js
function like(button, id) {
    let Button1 = $(button);
    let Button2 = $(button).siblings(".like2");
    let Button3 = $(button).siblings(".like3");
    let Button4 = $(".section2").find(".like4");

    Button1.addClass("pop");
    Button2.addClass("pop");
    Button3.addClass("pop");
    Button4.addClass("pop");
  


}
```

```css
.pop {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #32322e;
  border-color: #2f2f2c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">

  <button class="like" onclick="like(this, 347)">Button 1</button>
<button class="like2" onclick="like(this, 348)">Button 2</button>
  <button class="like3" onclick="like(this, 349)">Button 3</button>
  
 <div class="section2"> <button class="like4" onclick="like(this, 349)">Button 4</button></div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the siblings and nephews at the same time:

```
$(button).parent().find("button").addClass("pop");
```

Overall this is an anti-pattern. You would be better off simply adding a "like" class to each button that you want to be in the same group, then when any of the buttons in the group are clicked you can simply find all buttons with class "like".